# Is it possible to use Dell PERC H710 on a Dell R710/R610 server?

Tags: raid, dell, hardware-raid, dell-perc

Dell ships R710 with older RAID card H700 which has LSI 2108 chip and ships R720 with H710 card which has LSI 2208 chip. LSI 2208 is much better with SSDs in terms of performance.

I was wondering if it'd be possible to install PERC H710 RAID Card onto a older generation R710 or R610 Dell server and use without an issue.

Comment: Did you ever get the card working in the R710?

Answer (score 1):

This configuration doesn't appear to be validated/tested by Dell, so it would technically be "unsupported". 
I've not seen any postings around with test results indicating one way or the other, but LSI's [compatibility document](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/RAID%20Controllers/RAID%20Controllers%20Common%20Files/MegaRAID_SAS_Gen2CompatibilityList.pdf) for the 9266-8i (based on the same 2208 ROC) Indicates that the R710 is in fact compatible with this "generation" of cards.

If you're going to give it a try, I would anticipate that it would likely work... but if your intent is to "use without an issue", I'd suggest sticking with Dell-validated hardware configurations.

If you do try this out, please be sure to update with your findings so others have that info as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your servers are under warranty, I would say call Dell and see if it's supported.